# Add-PnPListItem fails when ampersand in the managed metadata field data

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, pnp-powershell

I have a list with managed metada column (column name - **Proficiency**).

I am creating the new record in my list with the following PnP command:

`Add-PnPListItem -List "Skill Matrix" -Values @{"PersonnelNumber" = 343; "Skill" = $skill; "Proficiency" = "P0 - No Skills"}`

It works perfectly when there is no special character (**&**) in the skills but it fails for the following Skills because of `&` sign:

`$skill = "SAP Skills|HANA Technical|Basis|Installation & Operations"`

I tried to replace it with `&amp;` but still it didn;t work.

Anyone please suggest me how to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: It needs to be `＆` and not `&`, can you try with this and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with unicode character and something to do with SharePoint not understanding `&` character, especially the Taxonomy APIs.

What you can do is to replace `&` with `＆` in your taxonomy label value in your script and it should work. They both look almost the same but are actually different.

You can check a reference here :- [Setting managed metadata fields using PnP PowerShell](https://www.m365-dev.com/2019/07/30/setting-managed-metadata-fields-using-pnp-powershell/)

Difference in pictures -

[image]

Comment: Thanks.... WIll try this ..

Comment: Any luck with this ?

Comment: it works .... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I test,@Gautam's way works well.
And there is another way to insert metadata.You could insert metadata value with term id,this way could avoid the influence of special symbols.
[image]

Official document for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works too. I am aware of this approch. But I do not have term ID handy with me. I have an excel sheet with approx 30,000 records, that contails term value along with other column values. I would have used this solution if I had term ID with me instead of Term value in the excel. Because also term count is more in terms sets, so i cannot get the term ID directly without writing code...

Comment: So i believe this will be indirect way in my case...